# CentOS conservative governor, nice error

Tags: centos, cpu-frequency

I changed my CentOS 6 CPU governor from ondemand (the default one) to conservative and got this after restarting the cpufreq service:

> /etc/rc5.d/S13cpuspeed: line 88:
>   /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/conservative/ignore_nice_load: File or
>   directory does not exist

So what should I do? Should I create the file and if so, what should I put there?

Comment: How did you change it? Did you Rest Art the cpufreq-daemon after Theiß change?

Comment: Yes, I did. I get the same error in the boot.log

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### For 3.x kernels

The interface to CPUFreq has changed in the newer kernels. This would include CentOS 6. You can read about the entire interface here in the Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) documentation titled: [Chapter 3. Core Infrastructure and Mechanics](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Power_Management_Guide/Core_Infrastructure.html#C-States).

Specifically the section on [CPUFreq Setup](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Power_Management_Guide/cpufreq_setup.html). Here are the steps required to set it up.

#### CPUFreq drivers

```
$ ls -1 /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/cpufreq/
acpi-cpufreq.ko
mperf.ko
p4-clockmod.ko
pcc-cpufreq.ko
powernow-k8.ko
speedstep-lib.ko
```

#### load appropriate driver

```
$ modprobe acpi-cpufreq
```

#### install cpupower tool

```
$ yum install cpupowerutils
```

#### view governors

```
$ cpupower frequency-info --governors
analyzing CPU 0:
ondemand userspace performance
```

So we currently only have these 3 governors loaded: **ondemand**, **userspace**, and **performance**.

#### loading governors that are missing

You can get a list of all governors that are available like so.

```
$ ls -1 /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/cpufreq/
cpufreq_conservative.ko
cpufreq_ondemand.ko
cpufreq_powersave.ko
cpufreq_stats.ko
freq_table.ko

$ modprobe cpufreq_powersave
```

#### confirm modules thus far:

```
$ lsmod |grep cpuf
cpufreq_powersave       1196  0 
cpufreq_ondemand       10544  8 
acpi_cpufreq            7763  0 
freq_table              4936  2 cpufreq_ondemand,acpi_cpufreq
mperf                   1557  1 acpi_cpufreq
```

#### confirm which governors are loaded

```
$ cpupower frequency-info --governors
analyzing CPU 0:
powersave ondemand userspace performance
```

#### viewing current policy

```
$ cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 1.60 GHz - 3.20 GHz
  available frequency steps: 3.20 GHz, 3.20 GHz, 3.07 GHz, 2.93 GHz, 2.80 GHz, 2.67 GHz, 2.53 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.27 GHz, 2.13 GHz, 2.00 GHz, 1.87 GHz, 1.73 GHz, 1.60 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: powersave, ondemand, userspace, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.60 GHz and 3.20 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.60 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    2500 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
    2500 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
    2500 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
    2600 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
```

In the above output you can see my current policy is **ondemand**. To tune the policy and speed you use this command to do so:

```
$ cpupower frequency-set --governor performance
Setting cpu: 0
Setting cpu: 1
Setting cpu: 2
Setting cpu: 3
Setting cpu: 4
Setting cpu: 5
Setting cpu: 6
Setting cpu: 7
```

#### confirm new governor

```
$ cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 1.60 GHz - 3.20 GHz
  available frequency steps: 3.20 GHz, 3.20 GHz, 3.07 GHz, 2.93 GHz, 2.80 GHz, 2.67 GHz, 2.53 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.27 GHz, 2.13 GHz, 2.00 GHz, 1.87 GHz, 1.73 GHz, 1.60 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: powersave, ondemand, userspace, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.60 GHz and 3.20 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 3.20 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    2500 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
    2500 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
    2500 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
    2600 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
```

You can also tune the min/max CPU frequencies within a policy using the `cpupower frequency-set --min <freq> --max <freq>`. See this [page for more details on what you can do with `cpupower frequency-set`](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Power_Management_Guide/tuning_cpufreq_policy_and_speed.html).

#### doing the above without cpupowerutils

So finally, if you don't have the cpupowerutils package installed, you can interact with it similar to how you did in the previous 2.6 kernels. Mainly you echo values into the `sysfs` filesystem.

#### for example

```
$ echo 360000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq
```

### For 2.6 kernels

You can read about the various [cpufreq features over on this site](http://www.pantz.org/software/cpufreq/usingcpufreqonlinux.html).

#### excerpt from [CPU frequency scaling in Linux with cpufreq](http://www.pantz.org/software/cpufreq/usingcpufreqonlinux.html)

> ignore_nice_load - This parameter takes a value of '0' or '1'. When
>   set to '0' (its default), all processes are counted towards the 'cpu
>   utilization' value. When set to '1', the processes that are run with a
>   'nice' value will not count (and thus be ignored) in the overall usage
>   calculation. This is useful if you are running a CPU intensive
>   calculation on your laptop that you do not care how long it takes to
>   complete as you can 'nice' it and prevent it from taking part in the
>   deciding process of whether to increase your CPU frequency. To turn
>   this on do the following.

```
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/ondemand/ignore_nice_load"
```

I'd put a 0 in this file since this should be the default. If you have any long running niced process, which I highly doubt, you can set it to 1.

Comment: I don't know why I can't create the ondemand directory with root account. These are the permissions `drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root    0 may 31 11:48 cpufreq`

Comment: @NotFromBrooklyn This directory is virtual. It will come into existence by loading the proper kernel module. Not vice versa.

Comment: You see, I do have /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0... and cpu1 ... but not /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq... as specified in my question.

Comment: @NotFromBrooklyn - are you still having an issue with this? The loading of the kernel modules as I described should create that directory. As Nils stated, that isn't a real directory, it's a API into the kernel to get/set a parameter to the kernel itself or a module that its loaded.