# CentOS 7 cpupower not setting the CPU's to maximum

Tags: centos, power-management, acpi, cpu-frequency

On my machine, i have power savings disable on the BIOS. When I run Ubuntu on this machine, the CPU's are running maximum at 2100 MHz.

However, when I'm running CentOS 7, even with the scaling governor set to "performance", the CPU's are not running full at 2100 MHz.

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
performance
performance
performance
performance

grep -i mhz /proc/cpuinfo
cpu MHz         : 1688.285
cpu MHz         : 2058.656
cpu MHz         : 1622.988
cpu MHz         : 2070.632
```

My application is a network processing application, so the CPU clock difference is resulting a performance difference.

I do not have cpuspeed,powerd, or any other power regulating services running.

So my question is, is this expected behavior given the cpupower is set to "perform"?
It seems CentOS is override the BIOS setting.

When I boot to Ubuntu, it just takes the BIOS settings and all the CPU's are running max.

Comment: What CPU do you have?

Comment: Take a look at the methods I desc. here in this U&L Q&A: [CentOS conservative governor, nice error](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77410/centos-conservative-governor-nice-error)

Answer (score 0):

The solution i've found is to disable intel pstate in grub

Answer (score 0):

With Centos/redhat I highly recommend using the tuned daemon to manage power states.  You can install it with yum install tuned
It sounds like you want:

```
tuned-adm profile latency-performance
```